# RefinableString## actual values are not shown in the refinement panel

Tags: sharepoint-online, refinement-panel

We are trying to create a new custom search refiner based on an existing managed property.We have mapped the existing crawled property in people results to the RefinableString## in order to add it to the refinement panel. Although it shows up in the list of refiners, the real values are not shown. It has been 4 days since we did the mapping. Can you please let us know how to proceed

Answer (score 0):

We had faced same issue in SharePoint Online environment. There is no problem with the process you followed. Once i read a SPO document where it was specified that continuous crawl happen every 15 mins and full crawl happens every 48 hours. But that was true for long back. Its almost over a year, we faced same issue, where full crawl happen after 7 days. After the full crawl we were able to get the right values.

It could be one of your case, you can raise a ticket with Microsoft for full crawl in such case.